# Why don't dFuse return EOS-token transactions sent from a smart contract?

Tags: dfuse

Why don't this dFuse-query return the latest incoming transaction from account cptblackbill?

../search/transactions?start_block=0&block_count=1400000&limit=20&sort=desc&q=receiver:eosio.token action:transfer (data.to:cptsambelamy OR data.from:cptsambelamy)

I sent this transaction from the wallet at bloks.io but it's not included in the data returned from dFuse. All other in/out-transactions for account cptsambelamy are returned correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK looks like you can find this transaction, it's just that the limit=20 you specified hides the result which is further down.

Also, I recommend you consider switch to our GraphQL streaming search API
https://mainnet.eos.dfuse.io/graphiql/?query=c3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uIHsKICBzZWFyY2hUcmFuc2FjdGlvbnNCYWNrd2FyZChsb3dCbG9ja051bTo4ODU5MzAwMCBxdWVyeToicmVjZWl2ZXI6ZW9zaW8udG9rZW4gYWN0aW9uOnRyYW5zZmVyIChkYXRhLnRvOmNwdHNhbWJlbGFteSBPUiBkYXRhLmZyb206Y3B0c2FtYmVsYW15KSIpIHsKICAgIGN1cnNvcgogICAgaXNJcnJldmVyc2libGUKICAgIHRyYWNlIHsKICAgICAgaWQKICAgICAgbWF0Y2hpbmdBY3Rpb25zIHsKICAgICAgCXJlY2VpdmVyCiAgICAgICAgbmFtZQogICAgICAgIGRhdGEKICAgICAgfQogICAgfQogIH0KfQ==